# Does Shia Islam prohibit saying "Ameen" after reciting al Fatiha?

Tags: salat, shiism, terminology

In Iran, people refrained from saying Ameen after prayer (which I'm accustomed to saying).  Chatting with a Shia friend today, he indicated I shouldn't say it, so I did some Googling, and a user of [ShiaChat](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/234993616-ameen-after-fatiha/) writes:

> First of all the word Amen is not an arabic word but a pagan God name and is not found in Quran and hadith.
>
> Secondly it was a bidah added much later on.

I'm not sure how reliable this source is, but this idea that it's forbidden seems to be repeated throughout the ShiaChat.  In this question, I want to confirm if Shia Islam indeed prohibits saying "Ameen", a claim also made [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/miscellaneous/difference-between-shia-and-sunni-namaz/).

**Question**: Does Shia Islam prohibit saying "Ameen" after reciting al Fatiha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shias don't say *آمین* instead as a non-wajib but mustahab act Shias say: *الحمد لله رب العالمین*.

> Imam Sadiq: Whenever you were in a Jama'at prayer and the Imam
>   finished his Hamd then don't say Ameen, say *الحمد لله رب العالمین*
>
> *(طوسی، محمد بن الحسن، التهذیب، ج2، ص74)*

Basically the Shias think this was the Sunnah the Sunnis think saying *آمین* was the Sunnah.

Comment: Well done, it is deemed as a nice brief answer. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 2):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

Based on my research, according to the hadiths of Ahlul-Bait, saying Ameen in prayer is not permissible, saying it breaks (invalidates) the Salah. In order to have a more perusing and to have a more elucidation, kindly following the source of the answer (as the detailed answer).

**Short answer:**

> In accordance to traditions narrated by the Ahlulbayt (as), saying
>   Āmīn in prayer is not permissible; furthermore reciting it
>   [intentionally] invalidates the prayer. In addition, there is no need
>   for evidence to prove the impermissibility [of saying Āmīn], in the
>   sense that prayer is an act of devotion (the laws for it are already
>   defined) and one can not add what they want to prayers as they wish.
>   If the permissibility of something has not been established in the
>   [Islamic] laws, this in itself is evidence that the action is
>   impermissible; because the overruling principle in prayer is the
>   impermissibility of adding anything to it. Also, reason dictates that
>   one should practice caution in this issue and not say Āmīn, since when
>   saying Āmīn one cannot have certainty that he/she fulfilled their duty
>   in prayer as opposed to when not saying Āmīn.

---

**Reference and entire answer:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8137)

Answer (score 0):

Ameen is not a part of the Surah Fatiha. Either pronouncing loudly or in heart, it breaks concentration in the prayer. It is however permissible to utter Ameen when one prays us. Mumtaz Ali Tajddin